# How to retrieve data from a single field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve an email address from a table in MySql using `$keyword` (keyword can be anything in the question field) to identify the row. I am successful in finding the row I need with the query below but it returns the entire row, how does one pull just the email out of the row and store it as `$email`?

**Query:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ask WHERE date = '$keyword' order by ask_id")
or die(mysql_error());
```

**Table:**

> | ask_id | store | fname | lname | email | phone | city| state | zip_code |question | sku | date |

Answer (score 4):

Just select only the column you need `email` instead of them all `*`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM ask WHERE date = '$keyword' order by ask_id")
```

Note that `mysql_*` function are deprecated, better to switch to either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). So you will be able to use `prepared statements` and you will avoid any risk of mysql injection, learn more here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I tried this and when I echo it to see what I get it says "Resource #4" instead of the email, if there a further step I need to take?

    $email = $result;
    echo " $email"

Comment: $email = $result; echo " $email";

Comment: @Scott try  to fetch an array first and then echo it `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); echo $row['email'];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31765/discussion-between-fabio-and-scott-morrison)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `email` FROM ask WHERE date = '$keyword' order by ask_id
```

Use code above instead. `SELECT * FROM...` in your mysql statement means select everything.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the obligatory mysql_* commands are deprecated, don't use them, kittens will die and your dog will get shot etc. For more on that, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

If you only want to retrieve one column from your MySQL database you can do so by specifying the column after your SELECT, instead of an asterisk. So you would have a query as follows:

```
SELECT email FROM ask WHERE date = '$keyword' order by ask_id
```

You can use this as follows in PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM ask WHERE date = '$keyword' order by ask_id")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

To reiterate, you should not be using the mysql_* functions. There are superior replacements available, as detailed in the question referenced above.

Comment: I've tried this and I echo the results to see what I get it says Resourse #4.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Then you need to do some more reading on how to use MySQL from PHP. A good start is http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT columnName AS email FROM ask WHERE date = '" . $keyword . "' ORDER BY ask_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $row['email']; // Here Do Anything With Email...
}

Comment: I tried that and get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/ask/admin_search/functions_search.php on line 20

Comment: @ScottMorrison AS assigns the data to column "Email" in your MySQL return set. It's not necessary in your example, as it just renames the column. Your problem appears to be to get the data from your MySQL result into a PHP variable. I recommend picking up some documentation on the technologies you intend on using and reading it.

Comment: Thanks WouterH I am with you on that, I've been reading this http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1371215343&sr=1-2 which has been great, but I have this very specific thing I'd like to accomplish today. I'm a noob to a lot of this. I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Alright, good luck with the reading :) Please see my updated answer for your specific case.